# docx4j: is there support for value attribute for ol li element?

Tags: docx4j

I have got a document that is going to show double column document. In HTML I am using `value` attribute of the `li` element in an ordered list (`ol`) to control the value counter of. In a two-column document the right column will follow the counter of the left column. It works in HTML, but when converting to word using docx4j, it is not respecting the overridden value attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for this in docx4j. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/pull/75) for this. When the pull request is merged, then this answer will be updated accordingly.

Meanwhile, in order to use this feature, use the maven repository `https://jitpack.io` and declare the dependency ( in gradle):

```
 implementation("com.github.naimdjon:docx4j-ImportXHTML:8.2.1-li-SNAPSHOT")
```

in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.naimdjon</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1-li-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to enhance at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/ListHelper.java#L603

Comment: Added PR for this: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/pull/75/files